# Magento change configurable option select into div style dropdown options

Tags: magento, parent-child, configurable

Is there a way/guide that will change the configurable option selection from select dropdown type into div / ul - li dropdown type on product view page? Because I need to add the stock status for each child options.

Comment: try to go through this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011604/magento-changing-the-dropdown-configurable-product-options-for-divs

Answer (score 0):

Change the select tag to UL, and the option tags to li. Update your javascript to handle this. You can use the below script and manipulate it for your requirements.

```
function UpdateProductAttribute(AttributeId,ValueId,Qty,ProductId)
{
var RunFunction = true;
if (!isNaN(Qty) && Qty < 1){
    RunFunction = false;
}
if (RunFunction == true){
    var CurrentValueId = $('attribute' + ProductId + '_' + AttributeId).getValue();
    if(CurrentValueId){
        $('attributeselect' + AttributeId + '_' + CurrentValueId).removeClassName('active');
    }
        $('attribute' + ProductId + '_' +AttributeId).setValue(ValueId);
        $('attributeselect'+ AttributeId + '_' + ValueId).addClassName('active');
    }
}
```

You need to provide the form with the super attribute id (ValueID) & product id, attribute id in script is the attribute id (static id for your attribute). Hide/shows for selected li elements is also handled by the above script (the active class).

Be aware that:

```
 $('attribute' + ProductId + '_' +AttributeId).setValue(ValueId);
```

Is for updating the input field value.